# Actual Implementation of a Multiplier

Tags: rf

In school I have learned in both systems and communication about multiplication blocks. I have been taught that these blocks create a sum and difference frequency and can be filtered to get just the sum or the difference.

What I am wondering is how to actually implement a block like this in hardware. I first thought about an OPAMP multiplier setup, but I didn't think something like this worked well for high frequencies like 900MHz or 2.4GHz. How do I go about finding a device that will do this block for me?

Comment: Take a look at the fundamentals video about the Gilber cell. The only prerequisite is that you understand long tailed pairs of differential amplifiers. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7nmmb0pqTU0

Answer (score 4):

Lookup "Gilbert Cell" and "Four quadrant multiplier".

More generally, look into "translinear circuits" which are more general, the multiplier being a special case.  The key idea is the logarithmic relation between the base-emitter voltage and emitter current.  Some number of transistors are connected with their base-emitter junctions in a loop. By Kirchoff's voltage law, the sums of voltages around this loop is zero, and by the logarithmic relation, you can say something useful about the **product** of emitter currents.  With cleverness in making use of that fact, you can design a multiplier.   Differential amplifiers are a relevant idea, just not the key idea.

Some articles:
http://www.analog.com/library/analogdialogue/archives/42-11/multipliers.html
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Translinear_circuit

and find the paper "Translinear Circuits" by Barrie Gilbert

and for a good read that covers much more but includes a nice little explanation of translinear circuits, look for the article "The Gears of Genius" in IEEE SOLID-STATE CIRCUITS SOCIETY NEWS, Fall 2007 issue.   This article is followed by one describing a very fast multiplier circuit.

Answer (score 1):

The [SA612](http://www.nxp.com/#/pip/pip=%5bpip=SA612A%5d|pp=%5bt=pip,i=SA612A%5d) is a popular device using a Gilbert cell multiplier; it's often used by radio amateurs for simple superhet and direct-conversion radio receivers. It won't go up to 900 MHz or 2.4 GHz, but is suitable for experimentation at HF and VHF.